# How can I be notified about state changes to a VPN adapter

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, networkmanager, notifications

On Ubuntu 12.04 - actually Kubuntu, but I am using NetworkManager, so the configuration should be the same - I have configured a few VPN connections.

Now, if I have a long-running up- or download, how can I ensure that all network traffic is stopped immediately and unconditionally if the VPN connection breaks off?

What I am looking for is some method of getting notified (I don't want to poll!) of the change. The rest (e.g. inserting netfilter rules) I can handle myself. I just need to find out how to get notified about a change to an established connection.

In case it matters, the configuration I am using is based on `tun0`. If other details are required, let me know in a comment and I'll add them to the question.

---

What I have tried so far:

- configure the main LAN connection (this is inside a VM, so there is only a LAN connection) to be manual
- configure the VPN to be automatic

then I figured that this isn't the route I want to take anyway, because I want to start my script/program to get notified only whenever I activate the VPN. I am not running on VPN all the time, but most of the time.

So basically I need to register for some notification as soon as a particular VPN connection is established and then get notified if something happens to it in order to tear down the main connection automatically in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkManager should be able to do this for you.  From the man page:

> Information about networking is exported via a D-Bus interface to any
>   interested application, providing a rich API with which to inspect and
>   control network settings and operation.
>
> NetworkManager  will  execute scripts in the
>   /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory in alphabetical order in
>   response to network events.

...

> Each script receives two arguments, the first being the interface name
>   of  the  device  just  activated, and second an action.
>
> Actions:

...

> vpn-up: A VPN connection has been activated.  The environment  contains  the  connection UUID  in  the  variable  CONNECTION_UUID.
>
> vpn-down: A VPN connection has been deactivated.

So it looks like you have two routes: tie into D-Bus to listen for events and act upon them, or drop some scripts into `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`. The latter seems the path of least resistance.